# Running a UI thread into a background worker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety, backgroundworker

As I know it is not possible to load a winform into DoWork of a backgroundworker because of the interaction between UI and the Worker thread,
but I found a way to do this, I defined another thread that shows a Form and then started that thread into the DoWork of the backgroundworker.
It worked and I can now control the process of that backgroundworker... but I'm not sure whether it is a Safe method or not. my simplified plan is :

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void UI1()
        {
            using (Form2 f = new Form2())
                f.ShowDialog();
        }
        Thread ui1;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
         ui1 = new Thread(UI1);
         Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
         temp.backgroundWorker1.DoWork+=new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);  
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        temp.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();        
        }
        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 100000;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
               progressBar1.Value++;
               if (i == 5000)
               {
                   ui1.Start();
                   temp.backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
                   temp.ew.Reset();
               }
               if (temp.backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                    temp.ew.WaitOne();
            }     
       }
    }
```

and in the Form2 :

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            temp.ew.Set();
            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: This is a perfect recipe for disaster. Why don't you just use the BackgroundWorker to update the "normal" UI thread (as this is already done for you)?

Comment: what do you mean "normal" UI thread ? i have not access to visual studio righ now but the whole plan is : the process of a backgroundworker stops until another Form opens and the user inserts information and presses a button, the new Form closes and the backgroundworker keeps on working.... so i need another Form which loads while the process stops

Comment: Your plan is backwards. If you need input from the user during background processing, you need to split up the process into chunks that can execute independently of each other.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated answer after your code examples

First of all, it is a very bad idea to have more than one UI thread or to access your UI from different threads. This is a source for many errors which will be very difficult to reproduce and debug.

So setting `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false` should never be used in productive code.

I will try to give you a code example that does (almost) the same thing as yours, but without any second UI thread.

#### Form2 and communication to Form1

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
  public Form2()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;
  protected virtual void OnButtonClicked()
  {
    EventHandler handler = ButtonClicked;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    OnButtonClicked();
    Close();
  }
}
```

This is my code for your `Form2`. It uses a `EventHandler` that `Form1` can subscribe to (as shown below) to get informed when `Form2.button1` has been clicked.

#### Form1 using `BackgroundWorker` and its events

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  private readonly BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
  private readonly ManualResetEvent ew = new ManualResetEvent(true);

  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    // this can all be done in designer too
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;

    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = 10000;
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    button1.Enabled = false;
    ew.Set();
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
  }

  private void form2_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    ew.Set();
  }

  private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
      if (i == 5000) ew.Reset();
      backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
      ew.WaitOne();
    }
  }
  private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    if (e.ProgressPercentage != 5000) return;
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ButtonClicked += form2_ButtonClicked;
    form2.Show();
  }
  private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
    button1.Enabled = true;
  }
}
```

So, with `backgroundWorker1.ReportsProgress = true` I indicate that this worker is going to raise `ProgressChanged` events. The good thing about the `ProgressChanged` event is, it is executed in your UI thread.

When a progress of 5000 is reported, I create the instance of `Form2` and register the `form2_ButtonClicked` method as handler for the `ButtonClicked` event of that instance.

Then I open the new `form2` using `Form.Show` instead of `Form.ShowDialog`, so it is not modal.

The worker thread itself has reset `ew` so the `ew.WaitOne` will now block until `ew` is set again. And this is what happens in the mentioned event handler `form2_ButtonClicked`.

As a bonus, I disabled `button1` in the first Form when it is clicked and re-enable it when the background worker is finished, so that the user cannot start another thread while the first is running. If you want multiple threads to run parallel, the code gets a little more complicated. But since there is only one progress bar, I assumed there should be only one thread at a time.

I hope this explanation helps you. And I repeat my adive to read the [official documentation at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx)!

---

#### Original post for historic completeness

The `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` method is actually already running in a different thread than the UI thread that started that background worker.

You are starting yet another thread which shows your dialog. In the end you could do that directly in that background worker:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  using (Form2 f = new Form2())
    f.ShowDialog();
}
```

Both ways are terrbile and **to answer your question**: your solution is **as unsafe as** opening the form directly from the background worker! The question is, **why** do you want to do that? Why should your new `Form2` should run in a different thread? Consider using [`Form.Show()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `ShowDialog` if you want a non-modal window (so that your user can switch to the parent window without having to close your `Form2`).

EDIT: Just to be sure: Use `Form.Show()` in the main UI thread, not in the background worker and not in the other thread. `Form.Show()` returns immediatly, so if you call it in one of the threads, this thread will terminate afterwards and probably close the window too.

Comment: the whole plan is : the process of a backgroundworker stops until another Form opens and the user inserts information and presses a button, the new Form closes and the backgroundworker keeps on working.... so i need another Form which loads while the process stops and i couldn't find a safe way for doing that yet

Comment: Sorry, but from that comment I only get a vauge idea of what you are trying to achieve, but it already sounds like there is a big misconception and design flaw. If you could explain more detailed (and show code) of what you are trying to do we could help you better. From what you've written so far, I'm still convinced that there is no need for a Form created on another thread.

Comment: I will edit my answer the next day when I'm on my desk again (writing on my phone now). I strongly recommend to read the official documentation for the background worker in the msdn! Especially keywords like `ProgressChanged` event, `ReportProgressChanged`, `CancelAsync` etc... I still can see no need to start the second Form in another thread.

Comment: @Hnz Done. Updated my answer.